# Endless loop with delay C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

For some reason my program is exiting

```
The program '[11632] Kiosk2.vshost.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Out of this:

```
public async void Update()
{
    short cooldown = 0;
    Console.WriteLine("Update function");
    do
    {
        if (secretKey >= 3 && cooldown == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(getGUID(), "Kiosk ID");
            cooldown = 9;
        }

        if (cooldown > 0)
            cooldown--;

        if (secretKey > 0)
            secretKey--;

        await Task.Delay(2000);
    } while (true);
}
```

The "Update function" WriteLine is being called. Here's the function where it's being called originally:

```
public Kiosk()
{
    Init();
    Update();
    hook();

    //  _urlRequestWorker = new Thread(Update);
    // _urlRequestWorker.Start();
}
```

Main function

```
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
    bool exists = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName(System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location)).Count() > 1;
    if (!exists)
    {
        Kiosk k = new Kiosk();
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("One instance of Kiosk is already running");
        Logs.saveLogs("Couldn't start instance of Kiosk because it's already running");
        Environment.Exit(0);
    } 
}
```

I have no idea why it auto exits, I could use `Thread.Sleep`, but I want to hook up a keyboard key listener to show me a messagebox.

Comment: You have async method that is called synchronously.

Comment: did you try to debug?

Comment: Update().Wait();

Answer (score 4):

Your call to Update() isn't blocking:  you're starting the call, but you still have to wait for it.

Remove the call to Update() from the constructor, then...

```
Kiosk k = new Kiosk();
k.Update().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

As an aside, you should really enforce the single instance via a named Mutex object: the approach you've used isn't guaranteed to work.

Comment: On your named mutex aside, I have an implementation of it on [code review here](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/156020/an-improved-single-instancing-library)

Answer (score 1):

Alright so this solved the issue

```
     public Kiosk()
    {
        Init();
        hook();
        var updateTask = Update();
        updateTask.Wait();
    }




      public async Task Update()
        {           
         do
         {
            //CODE HERE
             await Task.Delay(5000);
         } while (true);
        }
```